# TFS 2010 gated check-in using TortoiseSvn over SvnBridge

Tags: tfs, tortoisesvn, checkin, svnbridge

I have the configuration in the above title. I am using the TFS gated check-in feature which works fine if i use the TFS tools to check in my changes.

**A review of my understanding of the way it works:**

my changes are intercepted by the gated check in and put in a shelveset. The shelveset is pulled down by the build server, built, unit tests run, and gets checked in with **NO CI** appended to the end of the check in comment. When all that is done, a prompt to reconcile the workspace occurs.

**Using TortoiseSvn:**

i can commit code and update code just fine as long as I do not have gated check-ins set up.

With gated check-ins set up, the TFS server sends back a 500 error (see exception below) and the tortoiseSvn client shows the error labeled below, though the check in process continues. The build server builds, runs tests, and commits the code with no problem but this is pretty annoying and would be hard to convince other developers to use because you get the error on commit and then have to perform an update on the code to get the changes actually committed by the build server.

Thanks for any ideas or help.

**TortoiseSvn Error**

Error: Commit failed (details follow):
Error: Server sent unexpected return value (500 Internal Server Error) in response to
Error: MERGE request for '/mil-tfsprd-01/Inst%20Trading%20Support/Source/Main/ODS/Eliminator/Eliminator

**Stack trace from SoapException**

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Your check-in has been placed into shelveset Gated_2011-09-22_10.26.49.8403;US\RPieper and submitted for validation by build definition \Inst Trading Support\Eliminator.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at CodePlex.TfsLibrary.RepositoryWebSvc.Repository.CheckIn(String workspaceName, String ownerName, String[] serverItems, Changeset info, CheckinNotificationInfo checkinNotificationInfo, CheckinOptions checkinOptions, Failure[]& failures)
   at CodePlex.TfsLibrary.ObjectModel.SourceControlService.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Commit>b__3()
   at CodePlex.TfsLibrary.ObjectModel.SourceControlService.WrapWebException[T](WrapWebExceptionDelegate`1 function)
   at CodePlex.TfsLibrary.ObjectModel.SourceControlService.Commit(String tfsUrl, ICredentials credentials, String workspaceName, String comment, IEnumerable`1 serverItems)
   at SvnBridge.SourceControl.TFSSourceControlProvider.<>c__DisplayClass18.<MergeActivity>b__17(Activity activity)
   at SvnBridge.SourceControl.ActivityRepository.Use(String activityId, Action`1 action)
   at SvnBridge.SourceControl.TFSSourceControlProvider.MergeActivity(String activityId)
   at SvnBridge.Proxies.RemotingInvocation.Proceed()
   at SvnBridge.Proxies.TracingInterceptor.Invoke(IInvocation invocation)
   at SvnBridge.Proxies.RemotingInvocation.Proceed()
   at SvnBridge.Proxies.RetryOnExceptionsInterceptor`1.Invoke(IInvocation invocation)
   at SvnBridge.Proxies.RemotingInvocation.Proceed()
   at SvnBridge.Proxies.ProxyFactory.RemotingProxy.Invoke(IMessage msg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at SvnBridge.SourceControl.TFSSourceControlProvider.MergeActivity(String activityId)
   at SvnBridge.Handlers.MergeHandler.Handle(IHttpContext context, TFSSourceControlProvider sourceControlProvider)
   at SvnBridge.Handlers.RequestHandlerBase.Handle(IHttpContext context, IPathParser pathParser, NetworkCredential credentials)
   at SvnBridge.Net.HttpContextDispatcher.Dispatch(IHttpContext connection)
   at SvnBridge.Net.Listener.Process(TcpClient tcpClient)
   at SvnBridge.Net.Listener.Accept(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

Comment: Which version of TurtoiseSvn are you using and does it officially support TFS2010?

Comment: the SvnBridge version i am using (v6 Dec 30 2010) supports TFS 2010. the TortoiseSvn version i am using is 1.6.16, but the only compatibility issue should be with SvnBridge if one existed since TortoiseSvn is sending requests to SvnBridge which then sends them to TFS.

Answer (score 1):

SvnBridge doesn't support gated checkin - as you note, you'll fall back to this behavior.

If you're only using SvnBridge for Tortoise, you might want to check out the TFS integration into Windows Explorer instead which provides native access to TFS instead of through a bridge.  It's available in the [Team Foundation Server Power Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb980963).

Comment: Is the lack of support documented anywhere? I prefer to use TortoiseSvn if I can get it to work seamlessly like they advertise

Comment: Not that I've seen.  It's worth pointing out that svnbridge was not written by the TFS team and it's goal is to talk to codeplex in particular, not necessarily TFS servers in general.  Nor have I seen any advertisement for said seamlessness - and if I did see such an advertisement, I would be highly skeptical.